# Use trained model to predict classes from real images with SVM

Tags: python, classification, svm

I'm working on facial expressions recognition using SVM, the code i'm using extracts face landmarks using Dlib and train a multi-class SVM classifier to recognize facial expressions (emotions).

I've trained the SVM classifier and the model generated is saved to a .bin file.

Now I want to use this saved model to predict the expression from a real image, It means it takes a real image as input and as a results it returns the predicted emotion of that image.

This is the code I'm using :

```
def train(epochs=HYPERPARAMS.epochs, random_state=HYPERPARAMS.random_state, 
          kernel=HYPERPARAMS.kernel, decision_function=HYPERPARAMS.decision_function, train_model=True):

        print "loading dataset " + DATASET.name + "..."
        if train_model:
                data, validation, test = load_data(validation=True, test=True)
        else:
                data, validation, test = load_data(validation=True, test=True)

        if train_model:
            # Training phase
            print "building model..."
            model = SVC(random_state=random_state, max_iter=epochs, kernel=kernel, decision_function_shape=decision_function)

            print "start training..."
            print "--"
            print "kernel: {}".format(kernel)
            print "decision function: {} ".format(decision_function)
            print "max epochs: {} ".format(epochs)
            print "--"
            print "Training samples: {}".format(len(data['Y']))
            print "Validation samples: {}".format(len(validation['Y']))
            print "Test samples: {}".format(len(test['Y']))
            print "--"
            start_time = time.time()
            model.fit(data['X'], data['Y'])
            training_time = time.time() - start_time
            print "training time = {0:.1f} sec".format(training_time)

            if TRAINING.save_model:
                print "saving model..."
                with open(TRAINING.save_model_path, 'wb') as f:
                        cPickle.dump(model, f)

            print "evaluating..."
            validation_accuracy = evaluate(model, validation['X'], validation['Y'])
            print "  - validation accuracy = {0:.1f}".format(validation_accuracy*100)
            return validation_accuracy
        else:
            # Testing phase : load saved model and evaluate on test dataset
            print "start evaluation..."
            print "loading pretrained model..."
            if os.path.isfile(TRAINING.save_model_path):
                with open(TRAINING.save_model_path, 'rb') as f:
                        model = cPickle.load(f)
            else:
                print "Error: file '{}' not found".format(TRAINING.save_model_path)
                exit()

            print "--"
            print "Validation samples: {}".format(len(validation['Y']))
            print "Test samples: {}".format(len(test['Y']))
            print "--"
            print "evaluating..."
            start_time = time.time()
            validation_accuracy = evaluate(model, validation['X'],  validation['Y'])
            print "  - validation accuracy = {0:.1f}".format(validation_accuracy*100)
            test_accuracy = evaluate(model, test['X'], test['Y'])
            print "  - test accuracy = {0:.1f}".format(test_accuracy*100)
            print "  - evalution time = {0:.1f} sec".format(time.time() - start_time)
            return test_accuracy

def evaluate(model, X, Y):
        predicted_Y = model.predict(X)
        accuracy = accuracy_score(Y, predicted_Y)
        return accuracy(model, X, Y):
        predicted_Y = model.predict(X)
        accuracy = accuracy_score(Y, predicted_Y)
        return accuracy
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: I recommend that you look at the following website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html

Comment: The implementation is there. Consider passing `train_model=False` to your `train` function... Did you write that code?

Comment: Yeah I know it evaluates the whole validation set. I want to use the trained model .bin and develop an interface that takes as input a signle image and uses that model to predict the emotion and print it.

Comment: Please link the tutorial from where you are using this code, if any. Also, for scikit-learn models, look at how to [save and load them properly here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).

Comment: Here's the link : https://github.com/amineHorseman/facial-expression-recognition-svm